# ASCII Ice Cream

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N, and prints or returns an N×N ASCII art string whose top half is a semicircle made of `(`'s and whose bottom half is a downward-pointing triangle made of `V`'s, with spaces used as padding.

In other words, make an ASCII ice cream cone: (output for N = 17)

```
      (((((      
    (((((((((    
  (((((((((((((  
  (((((((((((((  
 ((((((((((((((( 
 ((((((((((((((( 
(((((((((((((((((
(((((((((((((((((
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
 VVVVVVVVVVVVVVV 
  VVVVVVVVVVVVV  
   VVVVVVVVVVV   
    VVVVVVVVV    
     VVVVVVV     
      VVVVV      
       VVV       
        V
```

## Examples

Here are the outputs for N = 1 to 5. **Note that for odd N, the triangle always must be the larger half.**

```
V

((
VV

(((
VVV
 V 

 (( 
((((
VVVV
 VV 

 ((( 
(((((
VVVVV
 VVV 
  V
```

[Here's an N = 101 pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/dZH8nnEB)

And here's an ungolfed Python 3 reference implementation:

```python
N = int(input())
ic = [[' '] * N for _ in range(N)]
for y in range(N//2):
    for x in range(N):
        if (x - (N - 1) / 2)**2 + (y - (N - 1) / 2)**2 < (N / 2)**2:
            ic[y][x] = '('
for y in range(N//2, N):
    for x in range(y - N//2, N - (y - N//2)):
        ic[y][x] = 'V'
for line in ic:
    print(''.join(line))
```

## Details

- Take input from stdin, command line, or as function argument. Output to stdout or similar, or you may return the string if you write a function.
- The cone portion should exactly match the reference implementation for all N.
- The ice cream portion does *not* need to exactly match the reference implementation as long as it is clearly in the shape of a semicircle for all N. (This is so you don't have to worry about slight differences in the semicircle due to roundoff errors.)
- There should not be any unnecessary leading spaces but there may be superfluous trailing spaces.
- The output may optionally contain a trailing newline.
- You may optionally use any 3 other distinct [printable ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) characters in place of `(`, `V`, and space.

## Scoring

The shortest submission [in bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins. Tiebreaker goes to the oldest submission.

Comment: Am I the only one who thought "IceCII ASCream" when I read the title?

Comment: @Sp3000 Jeez, I hope so...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## CJam, 46 bytes

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=17%7B%3AZ%7BZ%7BZ(2.%2F%3AR-zYR%3C)%3AP%23YR-zP%23%2BZ2.%2FP%23%3ESP%3F%7D%2FN%7DfY%7D~)

```
{:Z{Z{Z(2./:R-zYR<):P#YR-zP#+Z2./P#>SP?}/N}fY}
```

I believe this currently mimics the original specification exactly, which was required when I started producing this answer. There may be potential to save a few bytes by making the math less accurate to the original specification, but until I see a way to save more than one or two bytes doing so, I'll leave it as-is.

#### Explanation

```
{               "Begin block";
  :Z{             "For each y from 0 to input-1";
    Z{              "For each x from 0 to input-1";
      Z(2./:R         "Calculate the radius as (input-1)/2.0";
      -z              "Calculate the horizontal distance from the center";
      YR<):P          "Calculate the power to raise distances to: (y<radius)+1
                       (This results in Euclidean distance being calculated for
                        the ice cream and Manhattan distance being calculated
                        for the cone)";
      #               "Raise the horizontal distance to the determined power";
      YR-zP#          "Calculate the vertical distance from the center and
                       raise it to the determined power";
      +               "Add the horizontal and vertical distances";
      Z2./P#          "Calculate the solid distance threshold and raise it to
                       the determined power";
      >SP?            "If the solid threshold is exceeded, produce a space;
                       otherwise, produce the determined power digit
                       (This results in ice cream being represented by the
                        digit '2' and the cone by the digit '1')";
    }/              "End x loop";
    N               "Produce a new line";
  }fY             "End y loop";
}               "End block";
```

Comment: This appears to use `2`'s and `1`'s instead of `(`'s and `V`'s ?

Comment: @MarkReed This is allowed. Last line in the details section.

Answer (score 3):

### [inca2](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/master/README2.md) <del>129</del> <del>123</del> <del>121</del> <del>111</del> 107

This mostly uses the formulas from the python example, but using jot-dots and iotas instead of double-looping. The `i` function performs the circular test for the `j` function which invokes *jot-dot* upon it. And the `k` function performs the triangle test for the `l` function. The `c` function catenates the results of `j` and `l` and reshapes it to N×N.

*edit: -6* combine 2 maps into 1.
*edit: -2* remove useless ravels.
*edit:* nicer typescript.
*edit: -10* apply repeated expression array-wise.
*edit: -4* factor out repeated expression as a function.
*edit:* line-by-line commentary.

```
q:y-(n-1)%2
i:[((n%2)^2)>+/(qx y)^2
j:(~[y%2)i.(~y)
k:2*[x>[|qy
l:(@1+~]y%2)k.(~y)
c:y y#((jn<y),ly){' (V'
```

In more detail, the entry-point is the `c` function which takes one argument implicitly named `y`.

```
c:y y#((jn<y),ly){' (V' 
         n<y            } assign y to 'n'
        jn<y            } call j(y)
              ly        } call l(y)
      ((    ),  )       } catenate the results
      (         ){' (V' } map 0 1 2 to ' ' '(' 'V'
  y y#                  } reshape to NxN
```

The `j` function receives the same input value as its `y` parameter.

```
j:(~[y%2)i.(~y)
     y%2         } y divided by 2
    [            } floor
   ~             } iota. this generates the row indices 0..y/2
            ~y   } iota y. this generates the column indices 0..y
  (     )i.(  )  } jot-dot with the function i
```

The jot-dot here does the double-loop. It calls the `i` function with every combination of elements from the left and right arrays (0..n/2 and 0..n). So the `i` function receives as `x` the *y* index of the table, and it receives as `y` the *x* index. The names got a little backwards here :).

```
i:[((n%2)^2)>+/(qx y)^2
     n%2                 } n divided by 2
    (n%2)^2              } squared
                 x y     } make a 2-element array (x,y)
                qx y     } call q on this array
```

where `q` does

```
q:y-(n-1)%2
     n-1    } n minus 1
         %2 } divided by 2
  y-        } y minus that
```

back to `i`

```
i:[((n%2)^2)>+/(qx y)^2
               (    )^2  } square the result from q(x,y)
             +/          } sum the two numbers
            >            } compare the left side (above) with the right (=> 0/1)
  [                      } floor
```

The floor should not be necessary. But apparently there's a bug in the interpreter.

The `l` function works similarly to the `j` function, using a jot-dot.

```
l:(@1+~]y%2)k.(~y)
        y%2         } y divided by 2
       ]            } ceiling
      ~             } iota 0..ceil(y/2)-1
    1+              } add 1 => 1..ceil(y/2)
   @                } reverse => ceil(y/2)..1
               ~y   } iota y  0..y-1
  (        )k.(  )  } jot-dot using k
```

The `k` function yields a boolean scaled by 2 so the values can be distinguished from the ice cream values later on, in the mapping.

```
k:2*[x>[|qy
     x       } k's left arg
         qy  } y-(n-1)%2
        |    } abs
       [     } floor
     x       } left-hand-side again
      >      } compare 
    [        } floor (should be unnecessary)
  2*         } scale by 2
```

In action (piping through `tr` to remove tab chars which are the REPL's prompt):

```
josh@Z1 ~/inca
$ ./inca2 <icecream | tr -d '\t'

c1
V

c2
((
VV

c3
(((
VVV
 V 

c4
 (( 
((((
VVVV
 VV 

c5
 ((( 
(((((
VVVVV
 VVV 
  V  

josh@Z1 ~/inca
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>193</s> 192

Does not use strings, only math

```
N=input()
R=(N+1)/2;r=range(R)
s=lambda L,U:(10**U-10**L)/9
f=lambda N,m:s(0,N)+s(m,N-m)
g=lambda N,m:s(0,N)+s(m,N-m)*6
for i in r[1:]:print f(N,int(R-(2*R*i-i*i)**.5))
for i in r:print g(N,i)
```

`s(L,U)` returns a number of the form "`U`-digits with the rightmost `L` zeros and the rest ones"
`f(N,m)` returns an N-digit number with the inner section of `2` and an m-wide border of `1`on each side
`g(N,m)` does the same, but using `7` for the 'colour' of the inner section since it matches the texture of the cone more closely

Output

```
N=8         N=9
11122111    112222211
12222221    122222221
22222222    222222222
22222222    222222222
77777777    777777777
17777771    177777771
11777711    117777711
11177111    111777111
            111171111
```

Comment: Very unique way to do it :)

Comment: If only we can see the ice cream too :P

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6, 175

Pretty straightforward implementation without much golfing, just extraneous whitespace/punctuation elimination:

```
sub MAIN($d){my$r=($d/2).Int;for 1..$r ->$n
{my$y=$n-$r;my$h=sqrt($r*$r-$y*$y).Int;my$w=2*$h+$d%2;say
' 'x($r-$h)~'('x$w};for 1..($d-$r) ->$y {say ' 'x($y-1)~'V'x($d-2*$y+2)}}
```